# An iOS app for OTP that supports custom durations

Tags: ios

We use [TOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) for authentication purposes in one of our applications.

To generate access tokens, we use [FreeOTP](https://fedorahosted.org/freeotp/) on Android. Sadly, their iOS version isn't available on the App Store yet.

None of the availble iOS apps we looked into generate working tokens for our application. This seems to be caused by the fact that these apps don't support custom durations and always assume a validity duration of 30 seconds.

Comment: Does [tag:password-manager] apply here, or do we need a new tag?

Comment: @unor: OTP token generators aren't password managers as I understand the term, but there is a close relation. If it helps bringing in suggestions, I'd be in favor of it ;)